# C# alternative of rails migrations

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails

Does anyone know of a C# tool that behaves in a similar way to migrations in Ruby on Rails?

So a rails migration is a ruby file which contains a construct and destruct method.

The point of migrations are to make amendments to a database (either structural or data). It's possible to apply changes to the DB and also roll them back. It's a really neat solution.

for more information check this link [Rails Guides: Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

Comment: Many people here might know C# well but not RubyOnRails at all. Maybe if you come up with a short description on Migrations e. what it does they might be able to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [Fluent Migrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator#readme).

> FluentMigrator
>
> Fluent Migrator is a migration
>   framework for .net much like Ruby
>   Migrations.

Answer (score 3):

The main options I'm aware of are [migrator.net](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) and [rikmigrations](http://code.google.com/p/rikmigrations/)

Comment: As info to who might come here. Unfortunatly they seem to be dead today.

Answer (score 3):

How about octalforty-wizardby

http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a brand new one: https://github.com/dradovic/MigSharp

It has support for SQL Server 2005/2008/CE 4, Oracle, and Teradata. It also includes a nice validation framework that checks your migrations for potential cross-db issues and gives you hints to how to resolve them.

On top of that, it has a couple of more interesting features: multi-module support, deterministic SQL generation, etc. Read on here: https://github.com/dradovic/MigSharp/wiki/Feature-Overview

Comment: +1 I really like this one.  I've used Migrator.Net in the past, but it's been inactive for quite a while.

Comment: A new release is around the corner :)

Answer (score 1):

The Subsonic ORM has a built in migration feature. Here's a link to the docs - [3.0 Migrations](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/3.0_Migrations)

Comment: It is sad to see this project so long without updates...

Comment: That's too bad...I looked at it more than a year ago, and was impressed by the simplicity and how quickly you could come up to speed.  But the power of Fluent Nhibernate automapping eventually won the day in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Database/datastore agnostic solution: https://github.com/Mission3/migrations